# ElGamal Generator g problem

Tags: random-number-generator, elgamal-encryption

Having an ElGamal encryption scheme with p=19 which value can not be assigned to
g?

The answers were :  1,7,11,2

I think you can't assign value 1 to g.

Comment: What would happen to the public key if you use 1 as your g? How would your ciphertext look like?

Comment: As far as I know. I have my p=19 and g=1; I choose a random value a(1,p-2) , 3 for example. i know compute: g^a mod p -> 1^3 mod 19 wich is 1. So my Public Key Pb(19,1,1) and Pv(19,1,3). For encryption I choose a random k value : 7 for example. c1= 1^7 mod 19 = 1;  c2 is m(g^a)^k mod p . so c2 is m mod p. If m=2; 2 mod 19=2. So the encrypted message c is (1,2)

Comment: I am having a little bit trouble to understand why can't we use one of the values for generator g (1,7,11,2) and wich is the value or the values from these ones that we can't use

Comment: You agree if your public key is 1, then c2 will be the plaintext?

Comment: @DrLecter: I agree with user3626136, I don't see the issue; with $g=1$, you can encrypt just fine, and decrypt just fine.  There might be some minor security issuest; on the other hand, I don't see how any other value of $g$ would give significantly better security with $p=19$, so if we reject it on that basis, we'd have to reject all values of $g$ :-)

Comment: @poncho Yes, clearly. The point is not to have a toy example for the size of p, but to make clear that g=1 is always a bad choice ;) (if you want to have security and not just show that the correctness of the algorithms hold).

Comment: I just want to know if any of these g values (1,7,11,2) are a bad decision for assigning them. For any type of message, I don't seem to be a problem.

Comment: can't go into details now but I guess these elements are "forbidden" because g needs to be a generator. This means it has to have Order p-1 which always isn't the case for 1.

Comment: @SOJPM: no, ElGamal doesn't require that $g$ need to be a generator.  It does need to have an order which has a large prime factor; as I mentioned before, that disqualifies all values of $g$ in this example (as the largest prime factor here, '3', is scarcely large)

Comment: It's still 3 times as large as 1 though :P So for a multiple choice question the answer should be 1 I guess? I've often given answers that indicated that the questions were incorrect, but usually I didn't get any points for them. The only positive being the state exam for Economy II, where I got 0.5 points extra out of 10 for stating that the question was wrong *and* providing the answer they expected.

Comment: If ElGamal would be defined today, it would require a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group), with "find $h$, s.t. $h^r \neq 1$". In the original paper it actually was a generator, if I recall correctly. Anyway: $1$ as $g$ is always a bad choice, because *every* public key will be $1$ then. And not just if you choose the elements order (or a multiple of it) as private exponent.

Answer (score 1):

We can choose a generator which is a primitive root. We can check that 1,7,11,12 are not primitive roots for p=19. So they cannot be chosen as a generator.Given any number we can check if it is a primitive root or not.
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number).

Comment: Actually, it's 2, not 12, and 2 is a primitive root.  That being said, El Gamal doesn't require us to select a value which is a primitive root; for security, we do want an element with an order with a large prime factor; in the p=19 case, that's not possible.